# Updating Page Definition Queries with Python and data driven pages?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, data-driven-pages, definition-query

I have several annotation features that each have a tileID field. I would like to be able to enable the page definition query and select the correct Page Name Field to match the tileID field in all of my annotations.

Is there anyway to achieve this using python, ideally I would like to update several annotation layers at a time?

I could not seem to find any help in the documentation on this.  I know that it is possible to update a regular query through arcpy, but have not found a way to update page definition queries.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible, you would expect it to be settable as a property on the Layer object.

If it is not there then you may need to consider voting for or submitting an ArcGIS Idea.